# R: combining matrices by column name

Tags: r, matrix

matrix A is just a simple matrix with n rows and c columns
matrix B is just a simple matrix with n rows and d columns

A and B thus have identical rows n, but different number of columns
HOWEVER, some of the columns are identical (the name of the column and the values in that column)

I need to create a matrix C such that C has only those identical columns of A and B.

A and B have colnames() so that is how I though to do it but I am sure there is a faster way:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(A)){
    if(colnames(A)[i] == colnames(B)[i]){
        #do magic
    }

}
```

but this fails 2 places, A) obviously if the positions are different, so need "if (colnames(A)[i] is in colnames(B)) " and B) elements in B not in A are ignored; so overall this is a bad approach.

I used C = intersect(A, B) that did not work either; it gave me not what I wanted
any advice?

thank you

Comment: are you looking for `merge` ? or `cbind` ? can you give a reproducible example of what you want?

Comment: Do you want the columns in A that have the same name, but maybe different content, as a column in B? Anyway, try this `colnames(A) %in% colnames(B)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `intersect` on the names, and use the result for the index:

```
a <- matrix(1:15, 5)
b <- matrix(21:35, 5)
colnames(a) <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
colnames(b) <- c('A', 'C', 'D')

n <- intersect(colnames(a), colnames(b))
cbind(a[,n],b[,n])
##      A  C  A  C
## [1,] 1 11 21 26
## [2,] 2 12 22 27
## [3,] 3 13 23 28
## [4,] 4 14 24 29
## [5,] 5 15 25 30
```

I see that the question now says that the column values are the same, when the names agree.  Thus, it is only necessary to index one of the matrices with the intersection of the names.  Either will do:

```
a[,n]
##      A  C
## [1,] 1 11
## [2,] 2 12
## [3,] 3 13
## [4,] 4 14
## [5,] 5 15
```

Comment: This is great, you intersect the names and use that as a list of columns, coocoocool :) thx